# How to auto generate log file in VS Code after deleting it using python?

Tags: python, logging

I have this code to generate a log file in VS Code.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
```

Then, I deleted the `example.log` file thinking that it will auto-generate every time I run the code. But now, I am unable to generate a log file. So, I was wondering how can we generate a log with this code. What is the issue here?

Comment: Don't spam language tags.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
logging.basicConfig( handlers=[ logging.FileHandler('logs.log') ], level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Yeah, it is creating a file but it is not writing anything in the file. Why is that?